# Flutter Button Theme

Tags: flutter, material-design, themes, styling

I am styling a flutter app using Theme.
About Button, what is difference between **ButttonThemeData.buttonColor** and **ButtonThemeData.colorScheme.primary**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating a `ThemeData` object, if `buttonTheme` is not specified, it will be built from other properties such as `buttonColor`. If `buttonColor` is not specified, it will be a shade of the `primarySwatch`. If `primarySwatch` is not specified, it will be `Colors.blue`.

Similarly, if `colorScheme` is not specified, it will be built from other properties such as `primarySwatch`, in which case `colorScheme.primary` gets the value of `primarySwatch`, which is `Colors.blue` by default.

As for how the framework is using them for widgets:

- `buttonColor` is actually not used anywhere.
- `buttonTheme.buttonColor` is used for `RaisedButton`, `FlatButton`, `OutlineButton`
- `colorScheme.primary` is used for sliders, toggles, snackbars, as well as several Cupertino widgets.

There are several other properties of `ThemeData` that were meant to be made redundant by the introduction of the `colorScheme` objects, but they have not been deprecated and are therefore quite confusing.

Comment: Can you help me with buttonColor question link here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71479864/flutter-upgrade-to-2-5-3-causing-deprecated-issue