# Flutter upgrade to 2.5.3 causing deprecated issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-upgrade, themedata, buttoncolor

I have been been able to upgrade my code from flutter 1.2.0 to 2.5.3. Still I am getting some deprecated warnings as mentioned below:

info • 'buttonColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. No longer used by the framework,
please remove any reference to it. This feature was deprecated after v2.3.0-0.2.pre.
•

[image]

Please help me with a proposed fix for **buttonColor**.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `buttonColor` you could use [ButtonTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonTheme-class.html).

```
ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: appBarTheme,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    primarySwatch: primarySwatch,
    textTheme: textTheme,
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(buttonColor: AppColor.appBlueColor)
)
```

Read more on [ThemeData class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html).

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons

Here's an detailed explanation from official docs.

If you still have doubts feel free to ask.